# How do I display my test results on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

On my website I have 5 tests, they all work and their fine, now i would like to create a statistic for them, like how much people did them, how many people answered yes or no etc. The test results are `Posts` and they all have id's lets say they are `1` `2` `3` `4` `5`  How could I display these posts and statistics with php?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] with sample data and more information on the statistics you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a new category where you will put all your test-related posts.

Create this new category, put all the posts you want to show as test results inside and create a new page to call this posts.

**SCRIPT TO CALL POSTS FROM A SINGLE CATEGORY**

```
<?php

get_header();

$testResults = get_posts(array(

    'category' => '1', // put here the ID of your new category
    'numberposts' => -1 // -1 = all posts of this category. You can change the value to a integer (e.g. 5 to show 5 posts).

));

?>

    <?foreach ($testResults as $test) : ?>

        <h1><?php echo get_the_title($test->ID) ?></h1>

        <p><?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $test->ID) ?></p>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php

get_footer();

?>
```

You can show your statistics the same way. Create custom fields on each post showing your values, and you can handle this numbers inside the loop above.